# How to load several photos with assetForURL with a list of URLs

Tags: objective-c, callback, alassetslibrary

For a list of URLs I need to load the photos with ALAssetsLibrary:assetForURL, and this within one method.
Since this method works async but it is not iterating over the passed list of URLs, as we all know.
I found this snippet (which should work):

```
- (void)loadImages:(NSArray *)imageUrls loadedImages:(NSArray *)loadedImages callback:  (void(^)(NSArray *))callback
{
if (imageUrls == nil || [imageUrls count] == 0) {
    callback(loadedImages);
}
else {
    NSURL *head = [imageUrls head];
    __unsafe_unretained id unretained_self = self;        
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:head resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation;

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:assetRepresentation.fullResolutionImage scale:assetRepresentation.scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)assetRepresentation.orientation];

        [unretained_self loadImages:[imageUrls tail] loadedImages:[loadedImages arrayByAddingObject:image] callback:callback];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        [unretained_self loadImages:[imageUrls tail] loadedImages:loadedImages callback:callback];
    }];
}
}
```

How do I write the method definition in the form (above all the callback)

```
void loadImages(NSArray *imageUrls, NSArray *loadedImages, ...)  ?
```

How do I call this method from another method (again mainly the callback part) ?
Can the callback be in the calling method or a 3rd method needed for this? and how does this method need to be written?
I have found the snippet here: http://www.calebmadrigal.com/functional-programming-deal-asynchronicity-objective-c/

Answer (score 1):

Use  [**NSThread**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to call the **loadImages** method.

```
NSMutableArray *imageCollection = [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector (loadImages:)
                         toTarget:self 
                       withObject:imageUrlsCollection];


- (NSMutableArray *)loadImages:(NSArray *)imageUrls 
{
  ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *loadedImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  @try
  {
    for(int index = 0; index < [imageUrls count]; index++)
    {
      NSURL *url = [imageUrls objectAtIndex:index];

      [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

         ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation;

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:assetRepresentation.fullResolutionImage scale:assetRepresentation.scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)assetRepresentation.orientation];

             [loadedImages addObject:image];

          });

     } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

          NSLog(@"Failed to get Image");
     }];

    }
 }
 @catch (NSException *exception)
 {
     NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
 }
 @finally
 {
   return loadedImages;
 }

}
```

**Note**: With **ARC**,take care about **invalid attempt to access ALAssetPrivate past the lifetime of its owning ALAssetsLibrary** issue

[Here is the fix](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/15/solve-xcode-error-invalid-attempt-to-access-alassetprivate-past-the-lifetime-of-its-owning-alassetslibrary/) :)

Comment: Thank you Ramshad, that looks interesting. Does this mean that when reaching the next line below your first line the array imageCollection is filled, and therefore it's actually a sync call ?

Comment: And another thing: Since i'm not in a class (i write a native extension for Adobe AIR, therefore my .m file is only a set of methods) i get the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'" when trying to use detachNewThreadSelector toTarget:self. How can i get around this issue ?

Comment: the first line working on a separate thread.So it will not wait until the method execution. If u want to wait up to the execution of this method, then remove the NSSthread code and just call "[self loadImages: imageUrlsCollection]; "